# Перевод кода Python в C++

Tags: python, c++

переведите, пожалуйста код с питона на с++, заранее благодарен.

```py
def f(m):
    return max((w // (a + 2 * m)) * (h // (b + 2 * m)),
        (h // (a + 2 * m)) * (w // (b + 2 * m)))

n, a, b, w, h = [int (i) for i in input().split()]
l = 0
r = 10 ** 18
while r - 1 > 1:
    m = (l+r) // 2
    if f(m) >= n:
        l = m
    else:
        r = m
print(l)
```

c++:

```cpp
void f(int m,int w,int h,int a, int b) { 
    return min((w / (a + 2 * m)) * (h / (b + 2 * m)));
    return ((h / (a + 2 * m)) * (w / (b + 2 * m)));
}
```

Comment: А какие у вас были трудности с переписыванием на с++? Приложите, что уже накидали

Comment: И можете отформатировать вопрос, а то это даже не python.

Comment: Для подсветки кода под определенный язык нужно код обрамлять `\`\`\`python` в начале и `\`\`\`` в конце. А тут подсветка определилась под `с++`, мб у него приоритет выше

Comment: Я немного не понимаю как оформить функцию, все остальное переписал правильно, и спасибо вам за замечание по поводу подсветки кода.
Я попробовал так, но это неправильно
void f(int m,int w,int h,int a, int b)
{
 return min((w / (a + 2 * m)) * (h / (b + 2 * m)));
 return ((h / (a + 2 * m)) * (w / (b + 2 * m)));
}

Comment: @gil9red мне кажется по тагам по алфавиту

Comment: @GeraltLUL напишите что вы пытались в самом вопросе, а не в коментариях

Comment: @eri Смотрел видео человека, который решал задачи на бинарный поиск на питоне, только не понял как переписать функцию, но думаю это не так важно

Comment: @eri, скорее всего :) GeraltLUL, я перенес код из комментария, но там какая-то фигня, это не будет компилироваться :) Не бойтесь сами править вопрос (кнопка `править` под вопросом)

Comment: Я с телефона вылез потрындеть в комментах, верстать тут не очень удобно) а автора просил об этом потому как исправляя вопрос он может получше описать что ему не нравится

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int64_t n, a, b, w, h;

int64_t f(int64_t m)
{
    int64_t first = (a + 2 * m);
    int64_t second = (b + 2 * m);
    return max(w / first * h / second, h / first * w / second);
}

int main()
{
    cin >> n >> a >> b >> w >> h;
    int64_t l = 0;
    int64_t r = 1e+18;

    while (r-1 > 1)
    {
        int64_t m = (l+r)/2;

        if (f(m) >= n) l = m;
        else r = m;
    }

    cout << l << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Код переведён, но бинарный поиск сам написан  неверно, `while (r-1 > l)`, скорее так будет верно

Comment: Спасибо, да, я там опечатался.